# What is the fastest way to compare two sets in Java to get the elements that are in one set and not the other

Tags: java, performance, hashset

I've two Hashsets here **user** and **docbaseuser**

My Code:

```
Iterator iterator = user.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String isid = (String)iterator.next();
            flag = getCount(isid, Docbaseuser);
            if(flag == 0)
            {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Unique user found!");
            }

        }



private int getCount(String isid, Set<String> docbaseuser) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int flag = 0;
        System.out.println("execution reached getcount");
        Iterator iterator = docbaseuser.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            String id = (String) iterator.next();
            if(isid.equalsIgnoreCase(id))
            {
                System.out.println("MATCH !!!");
                flag++;
                break;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Is there any better way to compare the hashset user with hashset docbaseuser and fetch the elements from user hashsets which are not present in docbaseuser?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to find the difference between two data sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825684/efficient-way-to-find-the-difference-between-two-data-sets)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate as `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` is used. @Zeus07 But is it really necessary to use case insentive matching here?

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag=false; 
for(String files:user){
    for(String dbu:docbaseuser){
        if(files.equalsIgnoreCase(dbu)){
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    if(flag){
        //user already exists
        flag=false;
    }
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can achieve it this way:

```
public Set<String> fetch (Set<String> here, Set<String> notHere) {
    return here.stream()
            .filter(h -> !isIn(h, notHere))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}

private boolean isIn (String s, Set<String> set) {
    for (String str : set) {
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you don't need `equalsIgnoreCase` then you can do this:

```
public Set<String> fetch (Set<String> here, Set<String> notHere) {
    return here.stream()
            .filter(h -> !notHere.contains(h))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a set of all strings in `user` which are not present in `docbaseuser` as if you compared one by one using `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` but want the *O(1)* complexity of looking up elements in a `HashSet` or *O(log n)* complexity of `TreeSet` beware not to simply convert all strings to upper case or lower case by using `String.toUpperCase()` or alike. E.g. one might be tempted to use `new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`.

Here is a solution that behaves exactly like comparing strings using `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` with *O(1)* complexity at the initial cost of building a `HashSet` which is used as an index. But depending on context this could be maintained somewhere else and kept in sync with changes to `docuserbase` contents.

```
@FunctionalInterface
private static interface CharUnaryOperator {
    char applyAsChar(char operand);
}

private static String mapCharacters(String s, CharUnaryOperator mapper) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        chars[i] = mapper.applyAsChar(chars[i]);
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}

private static Set<String> stringsNotPresentInOtherSetIgnoreCase(Set<String> set, Set<String> otherSet) {
    Set<String> index = otherSet.stream()
            .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(
                    mapCharacters(s, Character::toUpperCase),
                    mapCharacters(s, Character::toLowerCase)
                    ))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    return set.stream()
            .filter(s -> !index.contains(mapCharacters(s, Character::toUpperCase)))
            .filter(s -> !index.contains(mapCharacters(s, Character::toLowerCase)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
}

private static void test() {
    Set<String> user = Stream.of("max", "John", "PETERSSON", "Tommy", "Strauß").collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<String> docbaseuser = Stream.of("Max", "Petersson", "Steve", "Brad", "Strauss").collect(Collectors.toSet());

    Set<String> usersNotInDocbaseuser = stringsNotPresentInOtherSetIgnoreCase(user, docbaseuser);

    if (!usersNotInDocbaseuser.equals(Stream.of("John", "Tommy", "Strauß").collect(Collectors.toSet()))) {
        System.out.println("Wrong result");
    }
}
```

Paste that code to some class and call `test()` in order to make sure that the `stringsNotPresentInOtherSetIgnoreCase()` method works correctly. Pay special attention to the strings `Strauß` and `Strauss` which are considered equal when transformed using `String.toUpperCase()` before:

```
System.out.println("Strauß".toLowerCase().equals("strauss".toLowerCase()));
System.out.println("Strauß".toUpperCase().equals("strauss".toUpperCase()));
System.out.println("Strauß".equalsIgnoreCase("strauss"));
```

Result:

```
false
true
false
```